# Validate a $_GET field across requests

Tags: php, forms

Example:

`site.com/?deleted_smth=7f6ed62`

7f6ed62 is unique and generated after a certain action completes. This ID is required to let the next request (redirect) know that a action was fired and completed, so it can display a certain message on the screen. After the message is displayed the ID is invalidated, so it can't be used again. So if I reload the same link 10 times, the ID should become invalid after then 1st request.

How can I find out if the ID is valid?

Right now the only possible way I see is to store the ID inside the database :(
Then after I do the check, I remove it from the db...

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Is it a security feature or more of a convenience feature that the message won't be displayed again?

Comment: not security, just convenience... I don't like seeing that message over and over again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a session (`$_SESSION['..']`) and delete after the first request.